# OS X UDP broadcast maximum packet size

Tags: python, macos, udp

The following code will result in `error: [Errno 40] Message too long`
on my macbook (running OS X 10.10.5)

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)

sock.sendto('a'*1473, ('<broadcast>', 9999))
```

I get `error: [Errno 40] Message too long` for any message 1473 or longer.

However, if I change `'<broadcast>'` to `'localhost'` or any non-broadcast IP, the messages longer than 1472 go through just fine.

I have done this same experiment on Ubuntu and CentOS. I don't get the `error: [Errno 40] Message too long` message on either of those machines.

Two questions:
Why does OS X behave this way?
Is it possible to increase the broadcast limit on OS X?

Comment: Probably the MTU on your NIC is 1500, which after you account for headers and such, only allows a UDP message payload of 1473. UDP will not split messages for you. On the other hand, your loopback interface generally has a much higher MTU (64k on my Linux system).

Comment: @twalberg hmmm. If I change '<broadcast>' to any other IP address it works fine. Any other thoughts?

Comment: @Stephen were you able to find a solution to this?

Comment: @ShaunBudhram yup, this did the trick: `sudo sysctl -w net.inet.udp.maxdgram=65535`

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work on my Mac - this value is set to 65535 and still getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

`man socket` has this to say about `SOCK_DGRAM`:

```
SOCK_DGRAM      Supports datagrams (connectionless, unreliable messages of a fixed maximum length).
```

Depending on other parameters of the socket (loopback vs actual network path, broadcast vs unicast, etc.) that "fixed maximum length" may actually differ, but it's still going to be a "fixed maximum length".

`man sendto` lists this under the ERRORS section:

```
EMSGSIZE The socket type requires that message be sent atomically, and the size of the message to be sent made this  impossible.
```

Which pretty much corresponds to what you're seeing - there is a "fixed maximum length" above which `sendto()` cannot send the message atomically, and refuses to split it for you. If you need to send more than that amount of data, you'll have to split it yourself.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the questions I asked: Why does OS X have this limit where other OSs don't? Is it possible to change the limit? Why is it just when you are sending to the broadcast address?